# Understanding this in call and apply

Tags: javascript

As per definition of call and apply, they execute function on given context.
But, following code returned `Object{}` for `this`

```
function Animal() {
    this.name = "Lion";
    this.id = 1;
    this.getInstance = function() {
        return this;
    }
}
var myObj2 = {};
var myObj = new Animal();
myObj.getInstance.call(myObj2); //Object {}
```

When I used self to store the this, then it returned Animal object.

```
function Animal() {
    self = this;
    this.name = "Lion";
    this.id = 1;
    this.getInstance = function() {
        return self;
    }
}
var myObj2 = {};
var myObj = new Animal();
myObj.getInstance.call(myObj2); //Animal {name: "Lion", id: 1, getInstance: function}
```

In both the cases, my understanding was it should return `myObj2`.
What is possible explanation for this?

Comment: `call` and `apply` both have two arguments, the first is whatever you want as `this` in the callback, the second argument is the arguments passed, call takes a comma seperated list, and apply takes an array.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, so in this case, I am passing this as myObj2. But, it's returning different values for this.

Comment: The variable `self` should be declared with `var` ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you're not returning `this`, but `self`, which is completely different ?

Comment: @adeneo How are they different?

Comment: The same way as `a` and `b` are different in `var a = 4; var b = 5;`. I updated my answer to provide a (hopefully) easier to understand but equivalent example.

Comment: I think you are believing that `this` is more complicated or JS more magical than it is. It's not. Consider `this` to be like any other parameter of a function, but which gets assigned a value automatically. It still behaves like any other variable. When you assign `this` to a variable, then you are assigning the current value of `this`, not some magic link to a virtual identifier.

Comment: @FelixKling Now, I understand difference between this and self. Thanks for clearing doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is possible explanation for this?

`self` was set when `var myObj = new Animal();` was called, at which point `this` referred to a new `Animal` instance.

Calling `myObj.getInstance.call(myObj2);` doesn't magically change the value of `self`. It still has the value that was set when `new Animal()` was executed.

Furthermore, each function has "their own" `this` and the value of one function's `this` does not affect the value of another function's `this`, nor does it have any impact on assignments that happened **in the past** (`self = this;` happened before `getInstance` is called and in a different context).

---

Here is a hopefully simpler, but equivalent example, which doesn't use `this`:

```
function Animal(foo) {
    var self = foo;
    this.getInstance = function(foo) {
        return self;
    }
}
var myObj2 = {};
var myObj = new Animal('abc');
myObj.getInstance('xyz'); // returns 'abc'
```

Both functions, `Animal` and `getInstance` have a parameter `foo`. When `Animal` is called, `self` is set to the value of `Animal`'s `foo` (`"abc"`).

Later we call `getInstance` with a different for its own `foo` parameter (`"xyz"`). However, that does not affect `Animal`'s `foo`, nor `self`, since we are only *reading* the value of `self`, which is still `"abc"`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use call, youe are telling the function that the parameter passed must work as "this" inside that concrete function, so, when you use call and pass myObj2, this = myObj2 inside getInstance method, what is why you get the empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Within the function declaration for `Animal()`, `this` equals the current instance of `Animal()`. When you assign the value of `this` to variable `self`, you're locking in that definition statically, meaning it won't change. It will always return `Animal()`.

When you used `call()`, you instructed the `Animal()` function to refer to `myObj2` as `this` - as if `Animal()` were a method of `myObj2`. So `this` equals the context that you passed, which is, in this case, an empty object literal.

Comment: Alright, the current instance of the function. Answer updated.